# Why does node.js, http-server, show that there are two request coming?

Tags: node.js

I have the following simple http-server setup using node.js:

```
var http = require('http');
var port = 12311

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

    console.log("Incomming request from " + req.connection.remoteAddress);

    res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end("test string");


}).listen(port);
console.log("Listening on " +  port);
```

As you can see, when a request comes in, I log it to the console. Now when I browse to `localhost:12311` the console shows that two connections have come in:

```
"E:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" hello-world-server.js
Listening on 12311
Incomming request from 127.0.0.1
Incomming request from 127.0.0.1
```

**Why is this?**

Comment: Might be the request for the icon. Look at the network tab in the developer tools of your browser.

Comment: @dystroy Yes! you are right, I tried logging `req.url` and guess what? It shows a request for favicon.ico. I guess I wast to fast to ask :)

Comment: Try logging more of the request object... it will show you the difference between the 2 requests.

Comment: You can log the req.url, properly it's the favicon.ico

Comment: @dystroy you can write it as a formal answer so I can accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's usually the request for the `favicon.ico`. Even if you don't have one, it's requested as the norm defines a default file path if you don't set the relevant `<link rel="shortcut icon"...` in the header.

The best ways to find about the requests are :

- client side, by opening the [developer tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) and looking at the *network* tab.
- server side, by logging `req.url`