# Why is there a double console.log?

Tags: javascript, node.js

### Description:

Hello, following a simple and straight forward tutorial. Everything works fine, but I was just curious as to why I'm getting a double `request received` when I refresh/access my page?

### Part of my code:

```
function onRequest(request, response){
    console.log('request received');
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write('Hello world baby');
    response.end();
}
//creating server
http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8888);
console.log("server has started");
```

### Screenshot:

[image: Image of double console log]

Comment: I bet it's because you're sending two requests.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny I don't see how I could be sending two requests.

Comment: Probably, your browser is trying to load `/favicon.ico` from your server.

Comment: Use your browser developer console to see actual HTTP requests.

Comment: Debug each request with `console.log('request received:', request, response);`

Comment: @gmo it'll be a lot of useless data, something like `console.log('request received:', request.url);` will be much more useful.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny you are right, it's trying to load the favicon.ico. I noticed after following your proposition: request.url. Thanks. Feel free to add the answer and I'll mark it as right.

Comment: @Grimbode there is alresy a bunch of identical questions on stackoverflow. For example, here are two top links from google: [1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22219463/why-does-node-js-http-server-show-that-there-are-two-request-coming), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9650253/node-js-beginner-why-does-this-receive-2-responses).

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny, I searched directly on SO. The propositions proposed by SO when I wrote the title of the question didn't correspond. I'll look more in depth next time.

Comment: Also make yourself familiar with your browser's debugging tools if you haven't already.

Comment: @Grimbode I think it's not because I was using another search engine, but because I was searching for a different phrase - `node.js two requests`.

Comment: @LeonidBeschastny you're right.. `request.url` would be much more specific here. Good catch!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser is looking for the `favicon.ico`, then it sends a request for the actual content. Try to `console.log` both the *request* and *response* to get more information.